# Can you copy only a specific area from one Canvas to another?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

As of right now Im rendering a map once to an offscreen canvas, wich then gets copied to the main canvas every frame, so I dont have to re-render every object on my map every frame, wich gets really laggy, my offscreen canvas needs to be relativly large to fit the whole map tho and the whole canvas gets copied onto the normal canas every frame wich also isn't that performant, so my question is; is there any way to only copy a section of a canvas to another canvas, so I dont have to copy the whole thing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData allows you to extract image data based on a X/Y coordinate and a width & height, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData allows you to place it at a X/Y coordinate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

allows you to extract image data based on a X/Y coordinate and a width & height, and

[`putImageData(imageData, dx, dy)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData)

allows you to place it at a X/Y coordinate.

Or use [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), that allows you to use the existing canvas as "input" directly, and you can specify X/Y and width/height for both the origin and the target:

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

Comment: Never use getImageData if you don't read the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) your canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const offscreen = Object.assign(
  document.createElement("canvas"),
  { width: 2500, height: 2500 }
);
makeNoise(offscreen.getContext("2d"));

canvas.onmousemove = evt => {
  const x = evt.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  const y = evt.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(offscreen, x - offscreen.width / 2, y - offscreen.height / 2);
}

// fills a context with noise,
// we use it only to draw somehing on the offscreen canvas
function makeNoise(ctx) {
  const img = new ImageData(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  const data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
Use your mouse to move the offscreen canvas<br>
<canvas><canvas>
```